# How to check if user is authorized to see a tab page in a teams toolkit project?

Tags: blazor, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, teams-toolkit, microsoft-teams-js

Using Microsoft teams toolkit i can add a tab page to a channel and display data from e.g. a database. The data displayed can be configured while tab creation using current the user permissions.
Using GetTeamsContextAsync() and GetTokenAsync() i can get the context / channel of the current page and the current user in teams.

How can i make sure some other user has access to view this data?

The tab is basically just a web page that is called from teams. I can even lanuch the tab in my web browser and someone could just copy the url. On the other side all members of the channel should be authorized to view the configured content.

How to achive this?

Tried to ask the Microsoft Graph Api for the user´s channel permissions.(/teams/{team-id}/channels/{channel-id}/doesUserHaveAccess) But it requires higher permission ChannelMember.Read.All

Also an option could be to store some secret in the tab´s url or other tabs parameters, but no idea where this information should be placed / is secure stored.

Comment: Please have look into this sample-https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/tab-sso/nodejs

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT thanks, can you point me to the right detail on the link? It demo app shows use of context and AuthToken(Client and Server side) access. Can´t find the authorization, it contains only authentication as far as i see? Thank you!

Comment: sorry for misunderstandings per my knowledge, when you create app using teams toolkit. When your app is running, navigate through the page to view the user  details. Select Authorize to let your app retrieve user details using Microsoft Graph. This is where the authorization check happens. If  the user is not authorized, they will not be able to proceed beyond this point. [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZINP.png If the user is authorized, their photograph and details will appear in your channel tab.  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JtkY.png
Are you trying the same?